# can ping but not arping via OpenVPN

Tags: linux-networking, ip-address, arp, mac-address, nmap

I'm working on a remote machine using OpenVPN at a customer's network. The IP addresses there change dynamically and (until they get hostnames to work properly which is not in my hands at this point) I'm looking for a way to find "my" machine quickly. Atm I'm trying it with MAC-addresses but won't succeed. I can detect machines using nmap, ping each one of them but arping fails.

Example:
ping:

```
ping 10.8.0.34
PING 10.8.0.34 (10.8.0.34) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.8.0.34: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=42.6 ms
64 bytes from 10.8.0.34: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=42.1 ms
64 bytes from 10.8.0.34: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=44.6 ms
```

arping:

```
arping 10.8.0.34
arping: Suitable device could not be determined. Please, use option -I.
```

arping (2):

```
arping -I tun0 10.8.0.34
arping: Device tun0 not available.
```

arping (3):

```
arping -I wlo1 -c 10 10.8.0.34
ARPING 10.8.0.34 from 192.168.178.26 wlo1
Sent 10 probes (10 broadcast(s))
Received 0 response(s)
```

I've tried all devices although I think tun0 should be correct for the VPN. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

OpenVPN tun point to point links do not have MAC addresses and thus you can't use `arping` with them. Or anything else that uses ARP or requires MAC addresses.

Answer (score 2):

In general, OpenVPN can use two kind of virtual network intefaces:

- `tun` device, which is virtual L3 interface. It doesn't have any MAC addresses, which are L2 stuff, so `arping` can't possibly work if OpenVPN is configured to use tun
- `tap` device, which is virtual L2 interface. It does emulate Ethernet, has MAC addresses, can be bridged by software bridge, can be used with VLANs and so on. `arping` could work on this kind of VPN, but it still depends on how exactly the server and client is configured.

Note, Windows machines only have a virtual `tap` driver. AFAIK Windows network stack doesn't have required hooks to implement a true `tun` device usable with OpenVPN. If you have a `tun`-type network and use Windows, it still shows a `tap` inteface, but then it works in so called `net30` mode, in which `tun` behaviour is emulated and `arping` wouldn't work.

A device name isn't necessary says it has a certain type, but usually nobody fiddles with that stuff `tun*` devices are `tun` and `tap*` devices are `tap`. It seems you have a `tun` mode, so all L2 stuff isn't available on it.